# how to get a string contained in a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that contains div in HTML code, i just want to retrieve the string contained in that div, like the word `LATTE` or `price:12` in the next code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        … 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="items">
            <div id="heapbox_46958322" class="heapBox">
                …
            </div>
            <select class="basic-example" style="display: none;">
                … 
            </select>
            <div id="dummy">
                …
            </div>
            <div id="gallery">
                <div class="item_block">
                    …
                </div>
                <div class="item_block">
                    …
                </div>
                <div class="item_block hasoptions">
                    price:12
                <div class="add_btn">
                </div>
                <div class="item_name">
                    LATTE
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="order_list">
            …
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        …
    </script>
</body>
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/43Lyc/2/)

- **UPDATE**

The answers help me get all the texts in all the divs that called item_Name , but i want it from the div i clicked as i'm using an onlclick event :

```
$('.item_block').on('click',function(){

// here is the tip

document.getElementsByClassName("add_btn").onclick =
    alert($(".item_name").text());    
.
.
.
```

Comment: You have jQuery and JavaScript tags, but I don't see either in your code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: isn't .text() what you are looking for?

Comment: In which div you want to string text?

Comment: Try jquery.com for that...

Comment: yea the whole code contains jQuery and JavaScript and i saw that you may need to be familiar with it in order to answer that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function.

Example:

```
$(".item_name").text();
```

This will retrieve the text inside all divs with the class `item_name`.

If you just want the text of the .item_name that you clicked on:

```
$(".item_name").click(function() {
  $(this).text();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UFMkQ/1/

Comment: the something is a have many divs from that type, and all i want is get the text that is inside the div i clicked, but when using onClick function with your code it gets me all the texts in all of that divs combined together

Answer (score 2):

Give that div a id

suppose `id="getText"`

In javascript

```
var value = document.getElementById('getText').innerText || document.getElementById('getText').textContent;
```

Comment: This is a better solution, as it doesn't require any external libraries, and works across browsers

Answer (score 0):

You could use `innerHTML` attribute of div to get the text inside.

```
alert(document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is help to you, In this i just add text to your `order_list` div for how to add text in div

```
$('#order_list').html('XYZ');
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/43Lyc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

innerText on the object should allow you to not only retrieve but also overwrite the text